# Bukkit Error: event cannot be resolved

Tags: java, bukkit

```
public void run() {
    if(spleggEnabled == 3){
        if(player.isBlocking()){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Projected Splegg!");
            WitherSkull head = (WitherSkull) ((ProjectileSource) player).launchProjectile(WitherSkull.class);
            BlockIterator iterator = new BlockIterator(event.getEntity().getWorld(), event.getEntity().getLocation().toVector(), event.getEntity().getVelocity().normalize(), 0.0D, 4);
        }
        if(player.isDead()){
                    spleggEnabled = 0;
        }
```

The error is on each `event.getEntity()`, and the error is `event cannot be resolved`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is this code? What method is it in?

Comment: @bcsb1001 edited to show the full code

Comment: Well, the `run()` method doesn't seem to be in a `Listener`, so what do you expect `event` to be? Is it some field? What class is it even in?

Comment: Is this in an event? Please show the FULL class code.

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like is that `event` is undefined.

If you are unsure of what `event.getEntity()` is, try replacing it with `head` or `player` in your code.

If you know what it is and what it does, make the `event` from your listener accessible (define it in the class as `public static Event event` and set it in your listener.)

You obviously stole some code from online without a single clue as to what it does. Next time, read the whole forum/blog/wiki post instead of blindly copying.